# Updating Angular Interpolation from component

Tags: java, angular

In my view I have interpolation for a users points balance as follows

```
<li class="pointsbalance" >Points Balance : 
                    <b *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
                            {{balance}}
                    </b>
                </li>
```

The points balance is updated throughout the site via api/service. A user can spend or buy points. The api works in that the call is made to the DB, it updates the points and returns the new points.

After a point change I call a function in the balance component but I can't get it to update the value in the view.

Example below

Buy points

```
buyMore(){
        //console.log("clicked")

        if (localStorage.getItem('userId') !== null){
            //console.log("loggedin in")
            var userID = localStorage.getItem('userId')


         this.messageService.updatePoints(userID)
         .subscribe(
             result => console.log(result)
         )
         this.comp.getMyBalance()

    }
```

Hits my message service, service calls routes/api and updates points in mongo. buyMore() function then calls getMyBalance() from balance component. That function is as follows

```
getMyBalance(){

            if (localStorage.getItem('userId') !== null){
                //console.log("loggedin in")
                var userID = localStorage.getItem('userId')


            this.points = []
            this.authService.getPoints(userID)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        console.log(data)
                        //this.points.push(data.points)
                        console.log(this.points)
                        this.balance = data.points
                        //this.balance.emit(this.points);


                    },
                    error => console.error(error)


                );

            }

            }
```

This works great on initial load, it's just when calling the component function from another component it won't update the view.

I'm not sure architecturally the best way about dynamically updating content in the view and if interpolation is the best option

Comment: You can use eventEmitter

Comment: invoke `this.comp.getMyBalance()` in subscribe method. Maybe you pull old data from mongo.

Comment: I tried  @Output() balance: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); and then in the function this.balance.emit(this.points), but it just shows [object object] in the view